# is it available to call the methods where in the vue component from the plugin?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I wanted to access the vue.data or methods in the plugin.
no matter what I tried several times, it didn't work.
such as eventBus, Mixin etc...
so I'm curious about the possibility to call the methods like that.
thank you for reading this question.

here is the custom component.

```js
<template>
  <div>
    <v-overlay :value="isProcessing">
      <v-progress-circular indeterminate size="64"></v-progress-circular>
    </v-overlay>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { Component, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class ProgressCircular extends Vue {
  private isProcessing: boolean;

  startProcess() {
    this.isProcessing = true;
  }
}
</script>
```

and this is the plugin source.

```js
import ProgressCircular from '@/components/ProgressCircular.vue';
import { VueConstructor } from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify/lib';
import vuetify from './vuetify';

export default {
  install(Vue: VueConstructor, options: any = {}) {
    Vue.use(Vuetify);
    options.vuetify = vuetify;
    Vue.component('progress-circular', ProgressCircular);
    Vue.prototype.$fireProgressing = function () {
      // it didn't work
      // I just wanted to access the method where in the Vue Component
      // ProgressCircular.startProcess();
    };
  },
};
```

Comment: There is no instance, so you can't use instance.startProcess. Should be this.startProcess but it will obviously fail in case there's no startProcess

Comment: I just wrote the name of the instance as an example

Comment: @EstusFlask I wanted to use the methods which access the member field in the Vue component.

Comment: Again, it should work as this.startProcess(), but it's unknown how $fireProgressing is used

Comment: @EstusFlask yes righty

Answer (score 0):

use the [plugin syntax](https://vuejs.org/guide/reusability/plugins.html) to extend vue like:

```js
Vue.use({
    install: Vue => {
        Vue.prototype.$fireProgressing = () => {
        };
    }
});
```

or

```js
Vue.use(YOURPLUGIN);
```

before you mount vue

Comment: but how can I access the method named "startProcess"?

Comment: pass it as a parameter inside `ProgressCircular` like `this.$fireProgressing(this.startProcess)` and `Vue.prototype.$fireProgressing = (startProcess) => startProcess();`

Comment: I tried like you said, but it doesn't work ㅠ

Comment: It's a mistake to make fireProgressing an arrow if it's supposed to access `this` in the first place. It's already workable the way it's written in the OP.

Comment: @JoonseoLee so try `this.$fireProgressing(this.startProcess.bind(this))`